# Copy row by row if value of cell is correct (by using Google Script)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to create a Google Script that copies rows from one Google Sheet into the same sheet but to different column based on the value of a cell.
Here's example:

```
    A    B   C   D   E   F
```

1| John      12   open

2| Nick     31   closed

3| Sara        12   open

4| Dany        32   closed

..n| Nick         221   open

If cell in column C is "closed", I need to copy columns A,B,C to D,E,F. If cell in column C is "open" ignore this and do not copy A,B,C to D,E,F.I know, that I can use normal function "if", but I need to use google script because I need to have in columns D,E,F pure text or a value (without formulas). Thank You in advance for help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question only contains requirements - it is not showing any efforts from your side to solve this problem yourself. Please add your attempts to this questions - as this site is not a free "we do your work" service. Beyond that: Please take a look at [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I removed the global set values and replace with only updating columns D,E,F when closed.  It will run a little slower but it shouldn't be messing with the formulas.

```
function copyIfClosed()
{
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sht=ss.getSheetByName('example');
  var lastRow=sht.getLastRow();
  var rng=sht.getRange(1,1,lastRow,6);
  var rngA=rng.getValues();
  for(var i=0;i<rngA.length;i++)
  {
    if(rngA[i][2]=='closed')
    {
      sht.getRange(i+1,4).setValue(rngA[i][0]);
      sht.getRange(i+1,5).setValue(rngA[i][1]);
      sht.getRange(i+1,6).setValue(rngA[i][2]);
    }
  }
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
}
```

Hope this helps.

Here's what my sheet looks like:

[image]

Comment: :) it's working almost perfect. In the above example if I have some function in D1, D3 or D5 fields are overwritten after runing script. For example if I have in D3 function "=B3+H3" after runing script field will be cleared :( How to changed it that fields will be not ovwerwriten?

Comment: Coping fields if is "closed" working perfectly but if is "open" data/functions in columns D, E, F are cleared :( Thank You for help

Comment: I'm sorry, data are not cleared but functions (are overwritten)

Comment: Okay made a change so that I don't mess with the content of d,e,f when open.

Comment: Cooper, thank you so much! Now everything works perfectly. Problem is solved :)